# Number of minutes until a bike is taken/placed in a public station

Tags: r

I have a sequence vector of # of bikes for every minute in a given public station. Suppose the values are these:

```
    num_biks <- data.frame(num_bikes = c(7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 8, 8, 7, 7, 9),
mins_until_arrival = c(2, 
      1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, NA), mins_until_taken = c(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 
      1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA))


num_biks <- cbind(num_biks, any_change = unlist(lapply(rle(num_biks$num_bikes)$lengths, 
  seq, by = -1)))
num_biks
#>    num_bikes mins_until_arrival mins_until_taken any_change
#> 1          7                  2                7          2
#> 2          7                  1                6          1
#> 3          8                  2                5          2
#> 4          8                  1                4          1
#> 5          9                  2                3          2
#> 6          9                  1                2          1
#> 7         10                  5                1          1
#> 8          8                  4                1          2
#> 9          8                  3                1          1
#> 10         7                  2               NA          2
#> 11         7                  1               NA          1
#> 12         9                 NA               NA          1
```

So in the first column there are 7 bikes in minute 0, 7 bikes in minute 1, 8 bikes in minute 2, etc..

I want to calculate two things: the number of minutes that pass until a bikes is **taken out** and the number of minutes that pass until a new bike is placed in the station.

For the first case the new column would be `mins_until_arrival`, where each row shows the number of minutes until a bike is **added** in the future. But note that from the 7th row on wards the number of bicycles decreases, so I need to calculate the number of minutes until there is an increase from there on wards, so the 12th row is when it increased at least one bike. Because we don't know when a new bike will be added, the last row is NA.

The second one I need is the inverse, so the number of minutes until a bike is **taken** from the station. That is the column `mins_until_taken`. Here you'll see that from the first minute it takes 7 minutes until a bike is taken from the station. Naturally, if the series ends and a new bike hasn't been taken out, I don't know when a new bike will be taken so something like NA's is fine.

I first tried using `rle` to calculate the minutes until there was any change (either taken or placing them) and tried identifying which were increasing or decreasing but it became too convoluted. I provide my `rle` attempt in case it helps.

Consider two things: I simplified the case to one station but I have to apply this to N stations on a dataset of nearly 30 GB so vectorized solutions are preferred, although I could translate any loops to vectorized if provided.

Can anyone point towards the right direction?

Comment: of course, you can't tell if, in a given time window, both events happened -- one bike arrived, one bike was taken

Comment: of course, I'm only interested in the recorded number. Some bikes could've been taken/arrived but only one of the two states was recorded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution with the `data.table`-package:

```
# load package and convert to a 'data.table'
library(data.table)
setDT(num_biks)

# create 'minutes' and 'change in number of bikes' columns
num_biks[, diff_num_bikes := c(0,diff(num_bikes))]

# calulate the minutes to an increase of the number of bikes
num_biks[, mins_to_increase := .N:1, by = cumsum(diff_num_bikes > 0)]

# calulate the minutes to a decrease of the number of bikes
num_biks[, mins_to_decrease := .N:1, by = cumsum(diff_num_bikes < 0)]

# calulate the minutes to any change in the number of bikes
num_biks[, any_change := .N:1, by = cumsum(diff_num_bikes != 0)][]
# set the last row of the increase column to 'NA'
num_biks[nrow(num_biks), mins_to_increase := NA]

# set the observations after the last decrease to 'NA'
num_biks[num_biks[, last(.I[diff_num_bikes < 0])]:nrow(num_biks), mins_to_decrease := NA]
```

Everything put together:

```
num_biks[, diff_num_bikes := c(0,diff(num_bikes))
         ][, mins_to_increase := .N:1, by = cumsum(diff_num_bikes > 0)
           ][, mins_to_decrease := .N:1, by = cumsum(diff_num_bikes < 0)
             ][, any_change := .N:1, by = cumsum(diff_num_bikes != 0)
               ][nrow(num_biks), `:=` (mins_to_increase = NA, any_change = NA)
                 ][num_biks[, last(.I[diff_num_bikes < 0])]:nrow(num_biks), mins_to_decrease := NA][]
```

this gives:

> ```
> > num_biks
>     num_bikes diff_num_bikes mins_to_increase mins_to_decrease any_change
>  1:         7              0                2                7          2
>  2:         7              0                1                6          1
>  3:         8              1                2                5          2
>  4:         8              0                1                4          1
>  5:         9              1                2                3          2
>  6:         9              0                1                2          1
>  7:        10              1                5                1          1
>  8:         8             -2                4                2          2
>  9:         8              0                3                1          1
> 10:         7             -1                2               NA          2
> 11:         7              0                1               NA          1
> 12:         9              2               NA               NA         NA
> ```

---

Used data:

```
num_biks <- data.frame(num_bikes = c(7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 8, 8, 7, 7, 9))
```

Comment: I'm squinting at the chained := ... instincts say you need to assign the final output there but I might be wrong (& currently afk)

Comment: @MichaelChirico nope, tested it :-)